# add css background to div

Tags: html, css

I have following document structure ,

```
<div style="background:#000000;">
    <input type="button" style="float:right" value="click here"/>
    <input type="button" style="float:right" value="click here"/>
</div>
```

but dont give me result I want.I want the background to be repeated over div body like in shown in image

[image]

Any help would be highly appreciated

Comment: how is it showing now?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Firstly, you're missing a 0. `#00000` isn't a valid hex colour code. Hex colour codes must either contain 3 or 6 hexadecimal digits. To resolve this, simply add a 0 (or remove two of the 0s):

```
<div style="background:#000000;">
    ...
</div>
```

From the [CSS Color Module specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-color/#rgb-color):

> The format of an RGB value in hexadecimal notation is a ‘#’ immediately followed by either three or six hexadecimal characters. The three-digit RGB notation (#rgb) is converted into six-digit form (#rrggbb) by replicating digits, not by adding zeros. For example, #fb0 expands to #ffbb00. This ensures that white (#ffffff) can be specified with the short notation (#fff) and removes any dependencies on the color depth of the display.

Secondly, when floating elements you need to clear them afterwards, as floating takes them out of the page's context. For this we can refer to [What methods of ‘clearfix’ can I use?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/211383/which-method-of-clearfix-is-best).

Comment: @captain I've edited my answer with a further fix and a link to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/211383/which-method-of-clearfix-is-best. :-)

Comment: I dont think `clearfix` was issue here.Can you elaborate a little?.The issue was div gets rendered with height zero when it contains floating elements.

Comment: @captain it has zero height *because* of the floated elements. The "clearfix" fixes this by stretching the containing element to the full height.

Comment: yes that I understood.But why `clearfix` here I dont think this will make any change to `div` with floated content.It will affect only to element appearing next to `div` with floated element.

Comment: Your `div` has 0 height, therefore it's not visible. This is the reason your background isn't showing up. In fixing the `clear` property, your `div` will have its height restored. http://jsfiddle.net/hzjv3/

Comment: Can you take a little effort of explaning me with a fiddle.I will be very thankful for your kindness

Comment: @captain I'd edited my previous comment to add a JSFiddle link. :)

Comment: Great.Thanks a ton for making me aware of `overflow v/s clearfix`

Answer (score 3):

```
<div style="background:#000; overflow: hidden">
    <input type="button" style="float:right" value="click here"/>
    <input type="button" style="float:right" value="click here"/>
</div>
```

Try this. Your Container includes floated divs so its rendered with 0 height.

Answer (score 1):

Add to parent div haslayout:

1. `overflow:hidden`
2. `div:after{content:''; display:block;
   clear:both;}`

Answer (score 0):

```
<div style="width:100%;padding:3px;background:#000;text-align:right;">
    <input type="button" value="Click" />
    <input type="button" value="Cancel" />
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Like this

**[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/2hs9u/1/)**

**css**

```
.divbg{
background-color:black;
    height:22px;
    padding:5px;
}
.divbg input{
    float:right;

}
```